# Angular TinyMCE open Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, tinymce

I have an `Angular` application and I am using `Tiny-MCE` editor.
I want to click on the new button I have added to the editor to open `Angular Material Dialog`.

When opening a dialog inside the new custom plugin that I have created I get the following error.

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')
```

to make sure that the dialog component is working fine I have added a button outside the editor and it is working fine.

please find the code sample here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k3nguv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Use `() => {}` instead `function() {}`.

Example:

```
onAction: () => {
   ...
}
```